# MiniProfiler not working after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I added `MiniProfiler` to my project using

```
Install-Package MiniProfiler
```

To try and work out why the app runs so slowly, and it seems to be working fine when debugging in VS.

However, after publishing the application and running it, the profile information is no longer displayed.

I followed [these instructions](http://miniprofiler.com/) to set up the profiler.

Is this a feature of `MiniProfiler`, and if so is there some of way of allowing this information to be displayed?

I tried publishing in debug mode but no luck.

Appreciate any help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the

```
if (Request.IsLocal)
```

from

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    }
}
```

It now appears to be working fine.

Comment: I've finally set up docs we can rapidly improve upon including getting started bits like this at http://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ - I hope you find them useful!

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks nick, I will have a look. Great package btw!